# I had Save variable name in database how i get value for them

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had save data in mysql

[image]

```
Array
(
    [template_data] => <p>{$ticker}</p><p>{$address1}</p><p>{$address2}</p><p>{$city}</p><p>{$phone}</p><p>{$website}</p>
    [date] => 2017-03-01
    [ticker] => HSPG.OL
    [address1] => SparebankgÃ¥rden
    [address2] => 
    [city] => BjÃ¸rkelangen
    [state] => 
    [zip] => 1940
    [country] => Norway
    [phone] => 
    [website] => http://www.hsbank.no
    [industry] => Money Center Banks
    [sector] => Financial
    [fulltimeemployees] => 
    [longbusinesssummary] => 
)
```

then i had `extract($array);`

then i had `echo {$ticker}` // its echo fine

but when i had `echo $template_data` // its not working

the out is

{$ticker}

{$address1}

{$address2}

{$city}

{$phone}

{$website}

but i want out

```
HSPG.OL

Sparebankayden

Norway

http://www.hsbank.no
```

the value are not echo for variable.

Can you help me guys.

Comment: Please post a part of the PHP script, so that we can see what you're actually doing. Telling us what you did without the code is most of the time useless.

Comment: $this->db->query('select * from templete');

Comment: extract($array);
echo "{$ticker}";
echo $template_data;

Comment: `echo $array['template_data'];`

Comment: its not working echo $array['template_data'];

Answer (score 1):

show number of variables successfully imported into the symbol table.
`$countVars = extract($array);`
`var_dump($countVars);`

And show your code fully.

Comment: and try extract with prefix.

Comment: and show your variable table: `$defVars = get_defined_vars(); var_dump($defVars);`

Answer (score 0):

May be your code is work fine but your `echo $template_data` is print `<p>` tag but value is null for that you not showing your value if see **view page source** from your browser then you will see your `<P>` and if have some error then you also see their.

When you check some value of any kinds of variable use this simple code :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_variable);
exit();
```

or

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($your_variable);
exit();
```

Comment: echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_variable);
print array 

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($your_variable);
exit();

print string